# DisplayPort audio shuts off when Brightness & Lock setting turns screen off

Tags: sound, 14.04, displayport

I'm using a Dell U2414H monitor with DisplayPort video/audio and a USB 3.0 hub for keyboard/mouse.

When the display turns off after *x* minutes, from the Brightness & Lock setting, the audio shuts off as well. The USB hub works fine, as my keyboard/mouse are plugged in there and that's how I wake the screen. I've only used Ubuntu 14.04 with this hardware, DisplayPort is new to me.

How can I keep the audio streaming when I afk and my screen turns off? (Monitor power button is still turned on.)

Comment: I was having the same problem. I finally found it. Its in system settings under brightness and lock.

Comment: Yes, turning off the screensaving feature will keep the music playing, but I wanted the display to sleep and keep playing music. Screens use most of the power anyways. Maybe this is working as intended, I'll have to plug an HDMI cable in to see if it does the same thing.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I ran my speakers straight to the PC, not as clean of wire routing, but it works 100%.I quit using display port, it was pretty glitchy.

Comment: I ran my speakers straight to the PC for simplicity. Displayport would also randomly fail to wake the screen from sleep, so I switched to HDMI. (haven't tried in a while though)